# How send with a <input type="file"> in a load or ajax - WEB2PY

Tags: web2py

Is there any easy way to send files to my controller from a .load view via a input type="file"? Or is there any way to do it with JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

By default, forms in Ajax `LOAD()` components will be trapped and submitted via Ajax. However, the method used for submission will not work for file uploads. Instead, you can override the default behavior by adding a "no_trap" class to the form element and setting up your own form submission handler.

In the view containing the form:

```
<form id="upload_form" class="no_trap">...</form>
```

or if the form is generated in a controller:

```
form = SQLFORM(..., _id='upload_form', _class='no_trap')
```

In the view containing the component, add an explicit "target" (for later reference):

```
{{=LOAD('mycontroller', 'myfunction.load', ajax=True, target='upload_form')}}
```

To handle the file upload, you can use the `FormData` API. For some ideas, see http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax. You might also consider using a library, such as [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

Once you have the `FormData` constructed, you can post to web2py as follows:

```
$.web2py.ajax_page('post', url, formData, 'upload_form', form)
```

where `url` is the URL of the Ajax component, `formData` is the `FormData` object you have constructed via your form submission handler, and `form` is the jQuery form object (i.e., `$('form#upload_form')`). That will post the form data to the URL and replace the "upload_form" target with the returned HTML.

Comment: FYI, there is now a Github issue requesting this feature: https://github.com/web2py/web2py/issues/1556.